Factorization of low rank matrices
In the context of machine learning, LoRAs (Low Rank Adapter) are using matrices of the form $A=PQ$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $P \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times d}$ and $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$ with $d \ll m,n$. Obviously $\text{rank}(A) \le d$, but I wonder in particular if there is a inverse statement, something like $\text{rank}(A) \ll n, m$ then there exist a decomposition into canonical projectors and a bijective $d \times d$ matrix.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition. In particular, the reduced SVD is what you want I believe

If $A\in \mathrm{Mat}_{n,m}(\mathbb R)$ then we may view $A$ as a linear map from $T\colon \mathbb R^n \;\to\; \mathbb R^m$, where for $v \in \mathbb R^n \equiv \mathrm{Mat}_{n,1}(\mathbb R)$ we let $T(v) = {A.\!v}$, for all $v \in \mathbb R^n$. If $A$ has rank $d$, then $\ker(T)$ is $(n-d)$-dimensional and if we set
$$
U = \ker(T)^{\perp} :=\{v \in \mathbb R^n: \langle v,w\rangle =0, \forall w \in \ker(T)\}
$$
then $\mathbb R^n = \ker(T)\oplus U$. Any $v \in \mathbb R^n$ can be written uniquely in the form $v= k+u$ where $k \in \ker(T), u \in U$, and $\pi(v) = p$. Thus
$$
T(v) = T(k+u) = T(k)+T(u) = 0+T(u) = \tau \circ \pi(v)
$$
so that $T = \tau \circ \pi$. If we pick a basis $B$ of $U$ then $A = PQ$ where $Q$ is the matrix $\pi$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and $B$ and $P$ is the matrix of $\tau$ with respect to the basis $B$ and the standard basis of $\mathbb R^m$.
